# C++ getting a character using cin.get, how to skip \n and grab only the first character?

Tags: c++, while-loop, character

I'm working on a school project, where a user should type in a choise for a switch/case menu. I've made an separate object to read in the menu. The program ia all about the Game of Life. I'm however struggling how to ignore all \n's and still reading only the first character. So when the user inputs \n \n \n R I like to return R, just as when then the user inputs \n \n RRR. However right now my code executes the command linked to R three times.

```
char wereld::leesoptie ( ) {    
char keuze = cin.get ( );       //So here the user will imput his \n \n RR
if (keuze == '\n') {
    while (keuze == '\n')       //I skip the \n's like this
    keuze = cin.get ( );
}                               
return keuze;                   //The returned value should be only the first real character of the string.
}//leesoptie
```

The code I use to execute the leesoptie function comes next:

```
int wereld::parameters (){
-----
keuze = leesoptie ( );
switch (keuze) {
        case 'T': case 't': return 0;
        ---
```

Comment: It looks like your switch may be off. Does it have any `break` statements in it?

Comment: @fuzzything44 You don't need to if you return in a switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;
```

This will read a single character ignoring any whitespaces (including newlines) by default. [See for more info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)